# use conditional in bash script to check string argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, sh

I am trying to write my shell script `thing.sh` so that upon making it an executable and running it with the single letter ``A" like so:

```
$ ./thing.sh A
```

I get the output

```
A
```

If argument 1 is not A, I want the output

```
Not A
```

Here is my code so far :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" -eq "A"]
then echo "A"
else echo "Not A"
fi
```

which returns, no matter what I enter,

```
./thing.sh: line 3: [:missing `]'
Not A
```

I am trying what I hoped would check something with one or several letters and compare it against the letter A; could someone tell me what I am missing to get this to work? Thank you

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What about the shorter :

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $1 == A ]] && echo "A" || echo "not A"
```

?

And a beginner version (identical logic) :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 == A ]]; then
    echo "A"
else
    echo "not A"
fi
```

Like Scott said, you have a syntax error (missing space).

### explanations

- I use boolean logic here. `[[ $1 == A ]]` is executed, and then if its true, `echo "A"` is executed, and if it's false, `echo "not A"` is executed, See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals
- `[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, I recommend `[[`.

Answer (score 6):

Change the first line to:

```
if [ "$1" == "A" ]
```

The -eq operator is for integers. And as someone else mentioned, the space does matter before the ']'.

See here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Answer (score 4):

Try putting a space between `"A"` and `]`.

Answer (score 4):

You need a space after "A"

```
if [ "$1" -eq "A" ]
```